# Performance Issue with collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In my query I have used `collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` which results in very bad performance (almost 2 minutes).

Could you please suggest how I can resolve my performance issue?

Basically I was getting this error:

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CS_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpConverted
(
    PolicyNo NVarchar(10),
    ShowToken NVarChar(16)
)

SELECT *
FROM #tmpConverted tpd
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM [dbo].CheckRecords cr
              WHERE cr.DetailRecord LIKE '%' + tpd.ShowToken + '%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS)
```

Sample data #tmpConverted:

[image: 1]

Comment: share your query execution plan

Comment: Seems like you're suffering of inconsistent collations.

Comment: A using a leading wild card *and* changing the collation of column both make the query non-SARGable; so yes it will take awhile. Apart from not changing the collation or not using a leading wild card, there's not a lot you can do about that as the entire column needs to be scanned.

Comment: but your performance issue is mostly because of `LIKE '%' + tpd.ShowToken + '%'`

Comment: You can insert data from CheckRecords into a local temp table, then perform your query. Data will be collated according to DATABASE_DEFAULT, so you shouldn't have to handle collation then. Depending on the data size, it might be faster

Comment: The issue is that it needs to do a scan of CheckRecords for each row in the temp table (a full scan in the cases no match is found)

Comment: What is the collation of `CheckRecords.DetailRecord` you can see this with `select collation_name from sys.columns where object_id = object_id('dbo.CheckRecords') and name = 'DetailRecord'`

Comment: Why don't you use the SQL_Latin1_General_100_CI_AS collation ?

Comment: Thank you all for the response. I tried using this collation "SQL_Latin1_General_100_CI_AS" - I am getting error => Invalid collation 'SQL_Latin1_General_100_CI_AS'.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your suggesting on inserting CheckRecords to temp table  , actually its not possible, because that table big one and also its not ready data , its raw data like "kgjh6876768jhghgjg87688787jhggjhgj hjgjh187668  yutuytuyt " in that I know which character starts with has "ShowToken", that's why I have to use WILD character option